# PHP date function convert the given date incorrectly

Tags: php, string, date, datetime

I am reading the dates of the current year from a csv file 
and passing it through the following date function.

`date('d-m-Y', strtotime($value[5]))`

As some point the converted date shows `2007` or `2009`.
Below is a sample in the format

From file( month date year and time) -> After conversion (d-m-y)

```
6/30/2018 10:10:11 PM -> 30-06-2018
6/30/2018 10:10:40 PM -> 30-06-2018
07-02-18 9:55 -> 18-02-2007
07-02-18 10:01 -> 18-02-2007
```

further ahead in the execution

```
8/31/2018 6:34:19 PM -> 31-08-2018
8/31/2018 9:43:07 PM -> 31-08-2018
09-01-18 10:00 -> 18-01-2009
09-01-18 10:04 -> 18-01-2009
```

Comment: it might be helpful to see the source data, especially where your code appears to fail ~ chances are it is the data that is haywire

Comment: what do you mean by `07-02-18` -> 7th month 2nd date 2018? or 7th date 2nd month 2018?

Comment: @RamRaider  https://3v4l.org/34OOY

Comment: should i share a file ?@RamRaider

Comment: @Lohit  i have asked you a question in comment.please answer

Comment: yes @AlivetoDie date on LHS is in the order of 7th month 2nd date 2018. I think the date format is haywire. should i share a file & how ?

Comment: tbh - I didn't see the `From file( month date year and time)`  - as @AlivetoDie pointed out the data `07-02-18` is ambiguous.. If you control the data written to the csv then I'd start there and make sure it is cohesive and all formatted correctly before trying to call the date routines

Comment: @RamRaider the data in the csv file is from a bio-metric attendance system and the dates do not have a fixed format. i thought the date() function would handle a date passed in any format and convert it to what is required.

Comment: `strtotime()` uses heuristics to determine that format. `/` _hints_ American dates, `-` hints British. `09-01-18` should be January 9 2018 because of the separator but you have 2 digit year so strtotime is confused. Ultimately, you're the one to know what the dates actually mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the core problem here. However, a quick fix would be to use a replace function as it clearly works fine with forward slashes:

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', '07-02-18')));
```

Result: [Here](https://3v4l.org/#preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to set input date format.

```
$dateStr = "07-02-18";
DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $dateStr)->format('d-m-Y');
// return 02/07/2018

DateTime::createFromFormat('y-m-d', $dateStr)->format('d-m-Y');
// return 02/18/2007
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/1uA4V)

Comment: i get the error     ` Call to a member function format() on boolean `. I am using codeigniter

Comment: @lohit you need to change the format based on input string.

Comment: @Lohit Because your input date isn't match with method format. e.g. for `07-02-18 9:55` you should use `createFromFormat('d-m-y h:m', ...` Check https://3v4l.org/MOVhI